# Get an exact error response from websockets (android)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to connect to server via websockets.
I was able to reach it via postman, but getting server error each time trying to connect.
I would like to see a response from server. How can I do it?

how I establish connection

```
val options = IO.Options.builder()
        .setAuth(
//        singletonMap("Authorization", "Token 123") // tried this option as well
        singletonMap("Token", "123")
    ).build()

private var mySocket: Socket = IO.socket("wss://api.myhost.com/v1/listen", options)
```

I have EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR handler:

```
socketDeepgram.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {
    it.forEach {
        (it as EngineIOException).printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

which gives me following trace:

```
2022-12-23 17:13:55.929 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err: io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: server error
2022-12-23 17:13:55.930 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.onPacket(Socket.java:552)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.930 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket.access$1000(Socket.java:29)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.931 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.Socket$5.call(Socket.java:335)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.931 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.emitter.Emitter.emit(Emitter.java:117)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.931 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.Transport.onPacket(Transport.java:124)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.931 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.access$700(Polling.java:17)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.931 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling$2.call(Polling.java:126)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.932 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.parser.Parser.decodePayload(Parser.java:127)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.932 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling._onData(Polling.java:131)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.932 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.Polling.onData(Polling.java:101)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.932 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.engineio.client.transports.PollingXHR$5$1.run(PollingXHR.java:115)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.932 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at io.socket.thread.EventThread$2.run(EventThread.java:80)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.933 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.933 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2022-12-23 17:13:55.933 5613-11317/me.echoist.app W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

socket client version:

```
io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0
```

I would like to know how to see a full response from ws server to troubleshoot (I was able to see clear error with postman)

Comment: stacktrace says "server error", what do you see at server side ? probably client side missing some configuration or protocol version number or something... if you put a reproducer to github ? will be easier to investigate the issue.